# Clarification regarding gmail message apis

Tags: gmail-api

What is the Order in which the message list returns the messages. i.e message.list api? Whether it is based on the message timestamp or any other field.

If I want to sync a very large mailbox and I fire a message.list api, then I get a pageToken for pagination, so how long is the pageToken valid? For eg if I get a page token X and I fire the api to fetch the next page after 6-7 hours will I still get the expected response.
As this pageToken validity is not mentioned in the gmail api doc, any approach on how can full mail sync be done if the service which is syncing the mailbox restarts.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the order of returned emails is "newest first, to older ones". I don't believe a pageToken would expire in 6-7 hours but why would you wait for so long to get the next page? If you care about getting new emails a few hours later then you want to use the history methods, starting with startHistoryId that you get from your full load.

Comment: No specific reasons to wait for 6-7 hours, that was just a rough estimate i gave to be 100 percent sure, my main concern is if my service faces a downtime of a few hours in worst case due to some reason then i wanted to develop a strategy where I could continue syncing the mailbox from the last received pageToken (given i can assume that it will be valid)

Comment: Definitely store the last pageToken in case your service goes down, later resume loading from that page. And if you get 410 (Gone / token invalid) then start a full sync again. Btw, if you plan to build for multiple mailbox providers, check out aurinko.io